# How to combine two selection with 1 option

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a `select option(drop down)` on my hmtl. I want to post this to database. Normally if I will **select** `"Selection1"` the `value="3"` will be selected and if I **select** `"Selection2"` the `value="4"` will be selected.

Now, I want that if I **select** `"Selection1&2"` the `value="3"` and `value="4"` will be selected or post to database.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to do that?

```
<select class="form-control" id='Selection'>    
    <option value="3">Selection1</option>
    <option value="4">Selection2</option>
    <option value="5">Selection1&2</option>
</select>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Use attribute `multiple` and set name of your `select` using `[]`:

```
<select class="form-control" id='Selection' name="myselect[]" multiple>    
    <option value="3">Selection1</option>
    <option value="4">Selection2</option>
    <!-- Following option can be removed -->
    <!-- option value="5">Selection1&2</option -->
</select>
```

Printing value of `myselect` on server:

```
print_r($_POST['myselect']);
```

you will see that you have an array with selected values.

Comment: Hi @u_mulder. thank you for this..I will try this and feedback

Answer (score 1):

If your third option acts as Select all option use Bootstrap frame work for select all functionality and for also better look and feel.

```
<div class="form-group">

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="Selection" class="multiselect-ui form-control" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="3">Selection1</option>
            <option value="4">Selection2</option>
            <!-- Following option can be removed -->
            <!-- option value="5">Selection1&2</option -->
        </select>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.multiselect-ui').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

"Select All" will act as your third option

Comment: Hi Radhesh, includeSelectAllOption is not recognizable.

Comment: Have you included bootstrap files ?? i.e [bootstrap.min.css](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css) and [bootstrap.min.js](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js)